# 5V or 3.3V supply voltage for rail-to-rail OpAmp with 0-3.3V output

Tags: operational-amplifier, level-shifting

I have a 0-5V signal that I want to quantize using an ADC with a 0-3.3V input range.

I want to lower the signal maximum amplitude with the following arrangement:

[image]

Is it better to power the second opamp with 5V or 3.3V?

##### Advantages I see for 3.3V:

- The output can never exceed the maximum input of the ADC (act as a protection).

##### Advantages I see for 5V:

- Can buy a dual opamp chip and use a single supply for both (both opamps can have better matching if this is useful for anything).

Comment: What ADC specifically? It may be possible to protect it with one diode and one resistor.

Comment: You won't get quite to either 5V or 0V with that arrangement. If you really need to accurately handle signals all the way  5V and 0V you'll need higher voltage rails (eg. +5.3V and -0.3V).

Comment: Yup.  "rail to rail" really means "rail to rail almost, and really phenomenally close compared to 1970's technology".

Comment: "Which is better" is an opinion question, which is discouraged here.  What does each one do (leaving it to you to decide what's better _for your application_) is nice and factual, and matches the ground rules of the group.

Comment: It's the built-in ADC of the nRF52840.

Comment: Subj' ADC input resistance guaranteed to be >1 MOhm. You may consider to not use opamps at all if signal source permits this. Input protection will be ensured by internal diodes and big enough divider resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't need opamps at all.
Output impedance of c12880ma is low, 150 ohms, and ADC's is high, 1M.
A simple resistor divider with impedances in the 10-100K range will reduce the level to 0-3.3V and provide enough sources resistance to limit current just in case 3.3V is exceeded.

[image]

(I see Vladimir suggested same thing as I was prepping this answer, so it must be right :)